# variable visibility in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to understand how variables are referenced and stay alive in Javascript.  In the following I have two types of object, a Note and an IntervalBuilder which takes a Note and creates
a second Note.

```
function Note() {
        this.key = 1 + Math.floor( Math.random() * 13); // from 1 to 13 inclusive
        this.setKey = function setKey(i) { key = i; };
        this.getKey = function getKey() { return this.key; } ;  // {return key} is a ReferenceError!!
}

function IntervalBuilder() {

    this.setPerfectFifth = function setPerfectFifth(root) {
    this.fifth = new Note();
    console.log("this.fifth: " + this.fifth);
    this.y = root.key;
    console.log("root.key: " + root.key );
    console.log("y: " + this.y );
    this.fifth.setKey( this.y + 4 );
    return this.fifth;
    };
}
```

With the above I can now do this:

```
var x = new Note();
var ib = new IntervalBuilder();
ib.setPerfectFifth(x);
```

However, the instance ib now has a member named fifth!  What I was hoping for was that I could assign the return value (a Note) from setPerfectFifth to a variable and let fifth vanish.  How is that done?

Many thanks for any help, I find lots of this very confusing.

Gerard

Comment: If you set this.fifth in IntervalBuilder, it is a public attribute on any instance. Try changing `this.fifth = new Note()` to `var fifth = new Note();`. This sill make it so that it isn't attached to the instance, and is private for the method. Then, change every occurrence of `this.fifth` in your function to just `fifth`, as it is now a private variable in the scope of that function. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: if `setPerfectFifth` doesn't set any property on `ib`, what does it set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you titled your quesion *variable visibility in javascript* what is basically going on is: In `this.fifth = new Note();` the keyword `this` references the instance (the ib of `var ib = new ...`). So you attach your newly created Note to the instance. In JavaScript, as long as a variable can be reached starting with the global Object (`window`, when you think of a graph), it won't get garbage-collected away.

What you want is: `var fith = new Note()`, which will create a local variable which will get freed as soon as the function execution ends. Clearly, every usage of `this.fifth` then has to be replaced by just `fith`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly what you want to achieve, but I think you want the following code structure:

```
// ==============================
// NOTE "CLASS"
// ==============================

var Note = (function () {
  // Constructor
  function Note() {
    this._key = 1 + Math.floor( Math.random() * 13);
  }

  // Getter
  Note.prototype.getKey = function () {
    return this._key;
  };

  // Setter
  Note.prototype.setKey = function (i) {
    this._key = i;
  };

  return Note;
})();

// ==============================
// INTERVAL BUILDER "CLASS"
// ==============================   

var IntervalBuilder = (function () {

  // Constructor
  function IntervalBuilder() {}

  // Private members
  var fifth = null,
      y = 0;

  // Setter
  IntervalBuilder.prototype.setPerfectFifth = function (root) {
    fifth = new Note();   
    y = root.getKey();
    fifth.setKey(y + 4);
    return fifth;
  };

  return IntervalBuilder;
})();

// ==============================
// CLIENT CODE
// ==============================

var x = new Note(),
    ib = new IntervalBuilder();

ib.setPerfectFifth(x);
```